# SSH connection issue on Fedora 30 with OpenSSH 8.0 (Using ssh-dss), still asking for password with public key setup

Tags: linux, ssh, security, fedora, openssh

I have already done some researches online, and the best solution seems to use a better algorithm to generate new key pairs. But right now I still need to use ssh-dss key pairs for internal automation.

> (I know that since openssh 7.0, ssh-dss is disabled by default, we need to
>   explicitly add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss` to ssh configuration
>   to re-enable it.)

Environmet:

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019

Linux hostname 5.1.19-300.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 22 16:32:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the checklist for what I have done so far:

- Create a user with password (some posts said that it might need a password)
- Create `.ssh` folder, set the public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys`, make sure that they have 700, 600 permission and right owner rather than root.
- Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make sure that we have`PubkeyAuthentication yes` (usually it's default value)
- Explicitly enable `ssh-dss`

  - Add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on server
  - Add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss` in `~/.ssh/config` on both server and client sides
- Restart sshd service to pick the new change

However, I was still asked for password.

- Check `/var/log/secure`, I see:

> `userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-dss not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`

- Check `ssh -Q key`:

```
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

Looks like that the `ssh-dss` should be in the list already, why I still see that error when ssh with private key file?

I did not got much more information from `/var/log/secure` after I set ssh log level to `VERBOSE`:

```
Jul 28 18:40:44 re-pkg-fedora30 sshd[1374]: Connection from 10.32.34.60 port 63863 on 10.140.143.132 port 22
Jul 28 18:40:44 re-pkg-fedora30 sshd[1374]: Failed publickey for mambop from 10.32.34.60 port 63863 ssh2: RSA SHA256:7EgHyu1SFM76cXlMGxHcvqg/C2xqbfbrQCfX5WCnOgc
Jul 28 18:40:44 re-pkg-fedora30 sshd[1374]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-dss not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes [preauth]
Jul 28 18:40:45 re-pkg-fedora30 sshd[1374]: Connection closed by authenticating user mambop 10.32.34.60 port 63863 [preauth]
```

Comment: Does your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file have the lines `PasswordAuthentication no` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` in it? Cause if so you shouldn't get a password prompt whether the pubkey auth fails or not. Also, have you made sure the client side config (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`)     have also had the necessary keytypes enabled?

Comment: Never mind, i missed it when I read the question the first time. You clearly do. You should probably check the server sshd, auth, and pam logs to see if you can spot             what sshd's reasoning for giving you a password prompt is.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Thanks for your quick response! Yes I got the reason by not know why: `userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-dss not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`

Comment: [Apparently](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html), on the client side you need to enable ssh-dss in the host key algorithms, not just accepted pubkeys. Try adding `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss` to your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Interestingly, when I do `ssh -Q key` my openssh installations all list `ssh-dss` as a supported key algorithm despite it being rather thoroughly and explicitly disabled in my configs (my openssh servers and clients are heavily hardened). So apparently that command's output isn't reliable for showing current configuration.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Thanks for your suggestion! Actually I did add that at my client side. Also, the same private key works with all my other agents, so that I do not think it's a client side problem...

Comment: Have you considered enabling VERBOSE log level to see if you can get more information from the serverlogs on the cause? `LogLevel VERBOSE` added to `sshd_config` would do it.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the logging for ssh, thanks for the suggestion! Lemme try that!

Comment: Verbose log does not provide much more information...Any other things I can try?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with RHEL 8.0, and initially went the same route, adding `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but it still didn't work. Then I realized that `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key` didn't exist, so I created that, but still no success.

Then I found [documentation about the RHEL 8 system-wide cryptographic policies](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening), which right at the beginning explains that a `LEGACY` policy level allows the DSA algorithm. And indeed, all that is required to make SSH pubkey authentication with a DSA key work (even without a restart of `sshd`) is

```
$ update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Note that this also weaken several other security aspects. I didn't care, because it's a short-lived test system, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, update policies command works perfectly. It should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went to Fedora 31 from 28 and had the same issue.  Not sure why, but I had exactly the same issues.  It told me that the key algorithm was there after doing the `-Q` key.  At one point it looked like I had got over that error but was then getting no key exchange algorithm and didn't know what I needed for DSA.

In the end I decided to upgrade to ECDSA with 512 bits and it appears to work for me.  I know that isn't going to help you because you probably have thousands of users all using the old certs, but wanted to let you know you were not alone with this issue.

Even though the OpenSSH documentation says you can downgrade, I am now wondering if that is really the case with OpenSSH version 8.  Version 7 was definitely supporting it because that was what I was doing after the last upgrade and before this upgrade to version 31.